# Thumbnail Meta Issue for Blog

Tags: html, metadata

I had a question for you about an issue I am experiencing. I recently designed a 'blog' site. It's not hosted on Wordpress or Wix. When I copy the link to a specific article and paste it into Twitter or Facebook, it only shows the image and the actual title of the website rather than the article title. As an example here, CNN's link shows the article image and title. Has this got to do with the meta tags? How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to use Structured Data:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article

You should insert following script in the page and update the `headline` and provide proper images for the value of `image` property in the JSON.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://google.com/article"
    },
    "headline": "Article headline",
    "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
    ],
    "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
    "dateModified": "2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00",
    "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Google",
        "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "https://google.com/logo.jpg"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You will also need to change other properties as per necessity.